# Bootstrap Datatable return 0

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datatables

I'm facing a problem with bootstrap `datatable` while using server side processing in wordpress. I've created a template which have the below `datatable` code. When I call the function it returns:

> {"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"2452","iTotalDisplayRecords":"2452","aaData":[["34","David","Carlson","carlson996@msn.com","Boulder","Colorado","USA","303","1","(NULL)"],["37`","test","test","teste@test.net","test","NC","USA","0","0","test"]

But `datatable` is not printing anything except "Processing". Then I checked the console and copy the url and pasted into url bar it return
0. And in console it says

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Here is my Data Table code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#testing').DataTable({
        "bFilter":true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost/site/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=fn_my_ajax_dataloader",
        "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']], 
        ]
    });
} );
```

Here is my Wordpress Function in function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_fn_my_ajax_dataloader', 'fn_my_ajax_dataloader');
function fn_my_ajax_dataloader()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $aColumns = array( "MemberID","FirstName","LastName","Email","City",
                        "State","Country","Phone","MemberStatus","SpouseName"
                    );

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "MemberID";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "wp_member_table";


    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }

    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= "`".$aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."` ".
                    ($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }

    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }

    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display 
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
        ";
    //$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery ) or die(mysql_error());
    $rResult = $wpdb->get_results($sQuery, ARRAY_A);

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";

    $rResultFilterTotal = $wpdb->get_results($sQuery, ARRAY_A); 
    $iFilteredTotal = $rResultFilterTotal[0]['FOUND_ROWS()'];
    //print_r($iFilteredTotal);die;
    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT($sIndexColumn)
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    //$rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery ) or die(mysql_error());
    $rResultTotal = $wpdb->get_results($sQuery, ARRAY_A);
    //$aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $rResultTotal[0]['COUNT(MemberID)'];
    //print_r($iTotal);die;


    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    foreach($rResult as $aRow)
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            //if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            //{
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                //$row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            //}
            //else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            //{
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            //}
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;


    }
        //print_r($output);die;
        echo json_encode( $output );
    }
```